# what is the difference between reading a resource from the class versus class loader?

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I am trying to read a text file, "text.txt", packaged at the root as a part of my jar file. in one case, my code calls `class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")` and in another case, my code calls `class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")`.

The first call gets the correct data but the second one doesn't get anything. any idea?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 InputStream is = null;
 try {
  is = TestLoadResourcesByClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  IOUtils.copy(is, writer);
  System.out.println(writer.toString());
 } catch(Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
  if(null != is) { try { is.close(); } catch(Exception ex) { } }
 }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 InputStream is = null;
 try {
  is = TestLoadResourcesByClassLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt");
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  IOUtils.copy(is, writer);
  System.out.println(writer.toString());
 } catch(Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
  if(null != is) { try { is.close(); } catch(Exception ex) { }
 }
}
```

let's say i have 2 jar files

- first.jar : contains TestLoadResourcesByClass.class (code to read test.txt)
- second.jar : contains "test.txt" at the root

and then i run my code as follows

```
java -cp first.jar;second.jar;commons-io-2.4.jar test.TestLoadByClass
```

i also get no output at the console. is that because the classes/resources in second.jar have not been loaded? in fact, i get a null pointer exception (input stream is null).

any idea on what's going on?

Comment: You can place inline code in a codeblock using `\`` or by clicking the `{}` button at the top.

Comment: sorry guys, so is complaining about my formatting, which i have already did the 4 space thing, still no luck.

Comment: A way to debug this is to call `xxx.getResource("/")` which should tell you where you are looking for the resource to stream.

Comment: @BevynQ when i do that for the first method, i get jar:file:/C:/test-cp/libs/testcp-SNAPSHOT-0.0.1.jar!/test.txt. for the second method, i get null. still that doesn't explain why one is valid and one is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained in the javadoc for [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). That method removes the `/` from the start of resource names to create the absolute resource name that it gives to ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream. If you want to call ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream directly then you should omit the `/` at the start.

Comment: you are right, when i remove "/" from the xxx.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.txt"), then both methods work.